# Pokémon GO AR+ doesn't work on my MI A1

Tags: pokemon-go, android

The Pokemon GO camera feature called AR + does not work on my Xiaomi MI A1 phone - with Android One OS - since it was released.

This option simply does not appear in the options.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix this?

Showing how my screen looks:

[image: config pokemon without ar+]

Showing how the screen should look:

[image: config pokemon with ar+]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Niantic support](https://niantic.helpshift.com/a/pokemon-go/?p=web&s=finding-evolving-and-hatching&f=catching-pokemon-in-ar-mode) page, Android devices must meet two requirements for AR+ to work

- Running Android 7.0+
- ARCore Support

If your device supports ARCore, you will need to install the respective app from the [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core). You can check which devices support ARCore [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices). However, the model Xiaomi MI A1 does not appear in the support devices, so your phone may not support the AR+ feature.